# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! in Angular2 while trying consume REST service with HTTP.GET

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

What I'm trying to achieve is to consume Restfull service with `HTTP.Get` in angular2, I'm just following some tutorial and read the documentation, but still I don't get it

Here is what I do, first below is my application structure, I created this project using Angular CLI Webpack

[image]

Then I created a service class using angular CLI command, "ng generate service restfull" then I updated my class so `restfull.service.ts` looked like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RestfullService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getDashboard(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/localservice/getdashboard/HUT17').map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }

}
```

Then here is my `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar';
import { RestfullService } from './restfull.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [NavbarComponent],
  providers: [RestfullService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  public active;

  constructor(private _restfull: RestfullService) { }

  getRest(){
    this._restfull.getDashboard().subscribe(
      data => {this.active = data},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('done loading foods')
    );
  }
}
```

I think that's all I need right? is there something I missed? it showed me this error in my firebug console:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class
>   AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No
>   provider for Http! ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   BaseException@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1811:23
>   AbstractProviderError@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28260:9
>   NoProviderError@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28297:9
>   ReflectiveInjector_throwOrNull@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56208:19 ReflectiveInjectorgetByKeyDefault@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56236:20
>   ReflectiveInjectorgetByKey@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56199:20
>   ReflectiveInjectorhttp://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56008:16
>   NgModuleInjectorhttp://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:40727:40
>   anonymous/_View_AppComponent_Host0.prototype.createInternal@AppComponent.ngfactory.js:18:56
>   AppViewhttp://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56772:16
>   DebugAppViewhttp://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56985:20
>   ComponentFactoryhttp://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:40380:27
>   ApplicationRef_http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:27082:23
>   PlatformRef_moduleDoBootstrap/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:26940:82
>   PlatformRefmoduleDoBootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:26940:13
>   PlatformRefhttp://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:26919:21
>   Zonehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3389:20
>   NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44849:32
>   Zonehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3388:20
>   Zonehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3282:25
>   scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3637:53
>   Zonehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3422:24
>   NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44840:32
>   Zonehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3421:24
>   Zonehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3322:29
>   drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3540:26
>
> ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object]

I think the point is "no provider for http" right? but I already put it at my `resfull.service.ts` class, what did i miss?

Comment: Where do you provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` or import the `HttpModule`?

Comment: at my restfull.service.ts, i have already provide HTTP_PROVIDERS but haven't import HttpModule, where should i import it? in the same class where HTTP_PROVIDERS was right?

Comment: you only import `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, you have to provide it to your root component via `providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` for your application, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ],
    directives: []
})
export class AppComponent {
...
}
```

Comment: thanks, it remove my error, but still haven't work, i will open new question since the error is not about http anymore

Answer (score 0):

Since RC.5 you should import `HttpModule` in your root module (typically `app.module.ts`) like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule, // here
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```